# File Visibility Using UploadSession in Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I am trying to upload a file to a Sharepoint document folder using the createUploadSession method. My request looks like the below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{MY-SITE}/drive/root:/cases/Test.txt:/createUploadSession
```

I then PUT the file contents using the provided uploadUrl in the response. While the upload is successful, no users can see the file in the folder. We are using Application permissions (not delegated) so there is no user directly assigned to the uploaded file. How do I attribute this file upload so other users can see the file? I am using Postman. I see examples of how to upload files, but none mention how to allow users to access the file once uploaded.

I tried applying a scope attribute in the body of the createUploadSession, but that did not work. JSON body below:

```
  "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "replace",
  "description": "description",
  "fileSystemInfo": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.fileSystemInfo" },
  "scope": "users",
  "name": "Test.txt"
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out this issue. The file needed to be checked in using the Check In Changes to a DriveItem resource.

```
POST /drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/checkin
POST /groups/{groupId}/drive/items/{itemId}/checkin
POST /me/drive/items/{item-id}/checkin
POST /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/checkin
POST /users/{userId}/drive/items/{itemId}/checkin
```

Once checked in, users are able to view.